# How do I get three column text layout with div without a corrupt footer?

Tags: html, css

So I've seen a countless number of posts regarding three columns using css to manually create the columns if you have three separate instances of text. The columns are there, but they are overlayed on top of the footer, and the page itself won't extend to display the content of the columns.

I have an example using JSFIddle and since it doesn't reflect the end result I'm trying to achieve, a screenshot of what I can see thus far. Any help provided would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with different methods for days now.

```css
header, footer, nav, article, figure, figcaption {
 display: block;
}

body {
 color: #666666;
 background-color: #f9f8f6;
 background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 font-family: serif;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 margin: 0px;
}

header {
 height: 160px;
 background-image: url("../images/header.jpg");
}

h1 {
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 940px;
 height: 130px;
 margin: 0px;
}

nav, footer {
 clear: both;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #aeaca8;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 30px;
}

nav li {
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 40px;
}

nav li a {
 color: #ffffff;
}

nav li a:hover, nav li a.current {
 color: #000000;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 height: 24px;
}

article {
 clear: both;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 100%;
}

hgroup {
 margin-top: 40px;
}

figure {
 float: left;
 width: 600px;
 height: 350px;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 20px;
}

figcaption {
 font-size: 90%;
 text-align: left;
}

a {
 color: #ff0080;
 text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2 {
 font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
 margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-weight: Bold;
}

audio {
 top: 5px;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.column-1 {
 width: 375px;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 15px;
}

.column-2 {
 width: 375px;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.column-3 {
 width: 375px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 float: left;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 1280px;
 margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
 border: 2px solid #000000;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-menu {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.menu-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #eef4fb;
 min-width: 160px;
 margin-top: 3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.menu-content a {
 color: #000000;
 padding: 9px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #aeaca8;
 display: block;

 -webkit-transition:
  color .3s ease-out,
  border .3s ease-out,
  background .3s ease-out;

 -moz-transition:
  color .3s ease-out,
  border .3s ease-out,
  background .3s ease-out;
}

.menu-content a:hover {
 background-color: #c5d9f1;
}

.nav-menu:hover .menu-content {
 display: block;
 margin-left: -61px;
}

.last-selector a{
 border-style: none;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

#footer {
 height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#footer > div {
 width: 4200px;
 height: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: #aeaca8;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 border: none;
 overflow: hidden;

 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation: newsbar 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation:    newsbar 20s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes newsbar {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2900px);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes newsbar {
 0% {
  -moz-transform:    translateX(0);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform:    translateX(-2900px);
 }
}
```

```html
<title>GazettE Kashi - Ugly</title>
<link href="../../../images/icon.png" type="image/png" rel="icon">
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
          <h1></h1>
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="../../../main.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../../../music.html" class="current">Music</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../../../pv.html">PV</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../../../live.html">Live</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../../../about.html">About</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </header>
      <audio id="song" controls autoplay>
          <source src="../../../music/ugly/ugly.mp3" />
          <source src="../../../music/ugly/ugly.ogg" />
      </audio>
      <div class="column-1">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dol amet</h2>
          <p>This is a bunch of random text simply to display the three columns of separate text!
      </div>
      <div class="column-2">
          <h2>Testing this</h2>
          <p>Testing a bunch of random text for the aligning elements of the css.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-3">
          <h2>Testing this!</h2>
          <p>just a bunch of more text to randomly fill space.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
          <div id="newsbar"><iframe src="../../../newsbar.html" width="3200" height="30" frameBorder="0" /></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: @dippas yes, it positioned it lower, but display: block; on the footer keeps the footer inline with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit footer style with `display:block` as it is inlining with columns.

Your rest of style properties same at is:

```
#footer{ 
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```